# Pseudo code for Pine Tree point per point generation? (2d)

Tags: graphics, drawing, pseudocode, point-clouds

NY is coming!) So let us assume we have some function like drawPoint(color, x, y) how would we render a pine tree?

Comment: A 2D rendering of a 3D pine tree, or just a 2D approximation of a "flat" pine tree ?

Comment: 2D approximation of a "flat" pine tree  (3d front side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system). See http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ifs_pine.png

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. Not a real answer:

```
n = 5;
p = {};
AppendTo[  p, {Brown, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, .5]}];

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  AppendTo[p, {Green, Cone[{{0, 0, i}, {0, 0, i + 3/2}}, (7 - i)^2/6]}];
];

Graphics3D[p, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]